# How microservice or web application respond to http request

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, webserver, web-frameworks

I want to know how a web service written using java and spring framework able to receive and respond to HTTP request using web server. Is web server is one of the component of a web framework or it is independent of what framework we use. Can we deploy service written in node + express on a tomcat server ? If web server is a part of web framework then what is the flow. How spring instantiate a web server and how multiple clients request are responsed. Is it true that tomcat server can create a max limit of 200 threads only . What if we have more than 200 client request, why the response does not get delayed.

Answer (score 0):

For handling http requests you will simply deploy the java/spring web application as war or convert into spring boot jar.

Tomcat can have more than 200 threads.

Can you deploy node+express on tomcat? the theoretical answer is possibly with some hack, but the practical answer is no.

Node is designed to run as a separate process. You can run your app using:
$node app.js